# How to write Unit test for Controller method with two parameters and what scenarios are required to test?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xunit, nsubstitute

I am new in Unit testing.  I would like to write unit tests for the Delete controller action. I want to use NSubstitute to mock all the dependencies. The current implementation is using an interface IRepository to abstract out calls to the underlying data source.

Controller

```cs
public ActionResult Delete(string fileName, bool isPublic)
{
    try
    {
        repo.DeleteDocument(new PortalDocument
        {
            Path = fileName,
            IsPublic = isPublic
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        EventLog.Logger.LogCritical(e, e.Message);            
    }
    return RedirectToAction(IndexViewName);
}
```

Interface for repository.

```cs
public interface IRepository<out T> where T: 
    CloudBlobContainer
{
    bool DeleteDocument(PortalDocument document);
}
```

PortalDocument Class

```cs
public class PortalDocument
{
    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about what you expect the action method to do. It should call DeleteDocument on the repo, and it should return a redirect result. Test that it does those two things. You can also have another test where your mock repo throws an exception, and make sure it catches it and logs it correctly, and returns the redirect result.

Comment: Hi Mason, Thanks a million for your Comment

Comment: I have tried one of the test to return redirected result and that is working, but can you please show me with an example that How to test this scenario "throws an exception, and make sure it catches it and logs it correctly".If possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you figured out the happy path scenario, of testing what happens when there's no exception. But now you need to test the unhappy path, that it behaves properly when an exception is thrown.

```
//arrange
var mockRepo = new Mock<DocumentRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);
mockRepo.Setup(r => r.DeleteDocument(It.IsAny<PortalDocument>())).Throws(new Exception("test"));

var controller = new DocumentController(mockRepo.Object);

//act
var result = controller.Delete("filename", true);


//assert
//make sure result is a redirect result
//but how do I test that it got logged?
```

Unfortunately, you'll find out you can't actually test that you logged something. Why? Because you have a static method call. Static method calls are not testable. Instead, you should follow the [dependency inversion principle](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/the-dependency-inversion-principle-with-c-examples/).

One way to fix this is to wrap your logging call with something that's injectable.

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void LogCritical(Exception exception);
}

public class EventLogLogger : ILogger
{
    public void LogCritical(Exception exception)
    {
        EventLog.Logger.LogCritical(exception, exception.Message); 
    }
}
```

Then your unit test becomes:

```
//arrange
var mockRepo = new Mock<IDocumentRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);
mockRepo.Setup(r => r.DeleteDocument(It.IsAny<PortalDocument>())).Throws(new Exception("test"));

var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger>(MockBehavior.Strict);
mockLogger.Setup(l => l.LogCritical(It.IsAny<Exception>())).Verifiable;

var controller = new DocumentController(mockRepo.Object, mockLogger.Object);

//act
var result = controller.Delete("filename", true);


//assert
//make sure result is a redirect result
mockLogger.Verify();
```

Note, I use the [Moq library](https://github.com/moq/moq4) syntax in my examples. You'll need to adjust based on your mocking framework.

If you're new to dependency injection, I highly recommend watching [Deep Dive Into Dependency Injection and Writing Quality Decoupled Code by Miguel Castro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6-QI1qN4pU).